# submit_tag value not passed as param when remote true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list with results where users have 2 options Save|Delete individual or multiple records. For this I have 2 submit_tags

So When I do

```
<%= form_tag some_path do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Hello World" %>
<% end %>
```

the submit_tag `{...,'commit'=>'Hello World'}` is passed to the controller inside the parameters hash

but as soon as do remote true

```
<%= form_tag some_path, remote:true do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Hello World" %>
<% end %>
```

the commit value is ommitted!

Any idea how can I fix it? I need to the user to stay in the same page whilst saving/deleting records... so remote: true is mandatory and since there are 2 submits I need some logic to do different things in the controller.

Thanks,

Comment: Try changing this line `<% submit_tag "Hello World" %>` to `<%= submit_tag "Hello World" %>`

Comment: Hi Pavan, that was a transcription error by code indeed have `<%=`

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same or a similar problem and I want to share my solution. In my case, I had a form defined like this:

```
<%= form_tag url, remote: true do %>
  ...
  <%= submit_tag t('.simulate'), id: 'btn_simulate', onClick: 'showSpinner()' %>
<% end %>
```

When the button was clicked, the request was sent without any parameters.

As it turned out the problem was caused by the *onClick* option. As soon as I removed it, the form worked as expected. To re-enable the onClick behavior, I instead added an event handler for 'ajax:before' to the form.